# how to do select more then 3 table add in select IN() function

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, U.l_name
 FROM posts M, person U
 WHERE M.uid_fk=U.p_id
    AND M.uid_fk in (
      (select send_id from friend_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1)
        or
     (select p_id from friend_request where send_id = '7' AND status=1) 
        AND
     (select send_id from follower_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1 AND M.uid_fk = '7')
        AND 
     M.uid_fk = 7
  )
 order by M.post_id DESC
```

and made by i can't got current data.

how to i get like this query

```
SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, U.l_name
 FROM posts M, person U
 WHERE M.uid_fk=U.p_id
  AND M.uid_fk in (1,2,3,4,7,8,9)
 order by M.post_id DESC
```

Comment: Var.1: use them as separate coinditions: `WHERE field IN (subselect1) OR  field IN (subselect2) ...`. Var.2: merge subselects: `WHERE field IN (subselect1 UNION subselect2 ...)`.

Comment: `SELECT M.post_id,  M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, U.l_name FROM posts M, person U WHERE M.uid_fk=U.p_id AND
M.uid_fk IN (
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(send_id SEPARATOR ',') from friend_request WHERE p_id = 7 and STATUS = 1),
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p_id SEPARATOR ',') from friend_request WHERE send_id = 7 and STATUS = 1),
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(send_id SEPARATOR ',') from follower_request WHERE p_id = 7 and STATUS = 1))
             order by M.post_id DESC`

i tried but i don't get proper data

Comment: Look carefully to my samples! There is no commas between subqueries in them!

Answer (score 0):

Hope It will Help.

```
SELECT M.post_id, M.uid_fk, M.message, M.image1,M.roles, M.created,U.uname, U.f_name, U.l_name
 FROM posts M, person U
 WHERE M.uid_fk=U.p_id
    AND M.uid_fk in ( SELECT id FROM (
      (select send_id as id from friend_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1)
        UNION ALL
     (select p_id as id from friend_request where send_id = '7' AND status=1) 
        UNION ALL
     (select send_id as id from follower_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1) 
 ) as ids

  ) AND M.uid_fk = 7
 order by M.post_id DESC
```

Comment: i got error :: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Updated Please Check Again.

Comment: i got empty data

Comment: The `AND` needed to be turned into a `JOIN`, not `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND M.uid_fk in (
  (select send_id from friend_request where p_id = '7' AND status=1)
    or
 (select p_id from friend_request where send_id = '7' AND status=1) 
    AND
 (select send_id from follower_request where p_id = '7'
              AND status=1 AND M.uid_fk = '7')
    AND 
 M.uid_fk = 7
```

-->

```
AND   ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM friend_request
                 WHERE p_id = '7' AND status=1
                   AND send_id = M.uid_fk )
        )
   OR ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM friend_request
                 WHERE p_id = '7' AND status=1
                   AND p_id = M.uid_fk )
  AND ( EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM follower_request
                 WHERE p_id = '7' AND status=1
                   AND send_id = M.uid_fk )
        AND M.uid_fk = '7' )
        )
```

You don't have balanced parentheses, so my parentheses may be wrong.